# Window vertically maximized beyond desktop size

Tags: gnome, window-manager, window

After navigating through the system setting to do post install tweaks on Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.1, I have a problem with the Sound Settings window in that it is vertically maximized way beyond my desktop size.
I have not seen the issue with any other windows thus far with any other setting windows or applications.

Any help would be greatly appreciated in getting the window resized.

Comment: Let us know if there is a way to reproduce the problem, so a bug could be reported about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xdotool` to resize the window:

After running this command, select the window which is too large; It will be resized to 300x300 pixels.

`xdotool selectwindow windowactivate getactivewindow windowsize 300 300`

Maybe you need to install it first:
`apt-get install xdotool`

An alternative way would be using the mouse together with the keys activating resize mode:

Try holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd> or the Windows key, then drag the mouse with the right or left button pressed anywhere inside the window.
There should be one mode where the window moved with the mouse - you can use that to move the oversized window into a better position without access to the title or border.
Also, there should be amode to resize the window by directly changing one edge.

Note on the `xdotool` command:

One could expect that `selectwindow windowsize 300 300` works, but with a reparenting window manager like `compiz`, it selects a child window of the one we intend to select, which leads to strange effects. The toplevel window is selected by `getactivewindow`, so we use that indirectly.

Comment: Running the xdotool selectwindow windowsize 300 300 has no effect...back to the drawing board.

Comment: That's not the command I proposed to use; try the other one and let me know.

Comment: Good job @Tim for reading the answer. +1 for cool solution

Comment: I ran the full command <xdotool selectwindow windowactivate getactivewindow windowsize 300 300> and the selection cross-hair cursor appears.  I then move to the Sound window, click in the title bar and the Terminal window resizes itself to 300 by 300.

Comment: Hmm..., let's see; Can you try to click inside the sound window, instead of the title bar? But if you can access the title bar, why not resize it step by step moving up and shrinking?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution using keyboard shortcuts: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Keys</kbd> (Up and Down)

Must keep the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>F8</kbd> keys pressed down while trying Up and Down arrows.
I have to do some times until the windows correctly resize.

Reference: [Move and resize windows - GNOME Help](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-windows-states.html.en)